# Cant install any sound or image packages for react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create sound player in my react native app, but I was trying to install a lot of various sound packages, and all of them are giving me pretty same issues, like this:
[image]

Without them, project compiles and runs fine.

UPD:
Added arrors as text:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-sound/sound.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' in '/mnt/c/users/user/desktop/adalo/audio_player/my-component/node_modules/react-native-sound'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-sound/sound.js 7:25-83
 @ ./src/components/CustomAudioPlayer/index.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./dist/input/runtime.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /mnt/c/users/user/desktop/adalo/audio_player/my-component/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js: Unexpected token, expected "from" (19:12)

  17 | const {pickScale} = require('./AssetUtils');
  18 |
> 19 | import type {ResolvedAssetSource} from './AssetSourceResolver';
     |             ^
  20 |
  21 | let _customSourceTransformer, _serverURL, _scriptURL;
  22 |
```

UPD2:
Running command `react-native info`
[image]

Comment: Please post text instead of images of text.

Comment: Please run `react-native info` in your project directory and post the result.